# .NET System::String to std::string

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

all, I'm using C++/CLI to write Winform. My operating system language is Chinese. I get the System::String from openfiledialog ,and use .NET transform the System::String to UTF8 encoding, finally I use StringToHGlobalAnsi to convert it to std::string.

However, if I open the Chinese named video,and feed it to ffmpeg, ffmpeg can open video correctly. But when I open Korea named video, ffmepg can't open video. Does anybody know how to open different language video which is different from operating system language?

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16 internally, not UTF-8, and you should call the `W` (wide char) Win32 functions instead of the `A` (ASCII) ones. You should therefore *probably* use `std::wstring` on Windows. You should use a proper marshaling function, such as `msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(theSystemString)`. But anyways, you won't get any more help here unless you provide a [mcve] and explain what *"open correctly"* means.

Comment: The problem here is: What kinds of filename strings does ffmpeg accept/expect?

Comment: I expect that in my Chinese operating system,ffmpeg can accept various language(Japan,Korea ...) file name.What should I do on this file name System::String before feeding in ffmeg.

Comment: When a particular file failed with a Korean name, what happens if you have that exact same name on Chinese Windows? What happens if you have that exact same name on English Windows? Please provide the filename that's failing, and show us how you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys !
I follow  Lucas's suggestion. Here is the code which can open different language video file name.

My native dll API:

```
OpenVideo(char* video_path);
```

My code in C++/CLI:

```
System::String^ multi_language_str = str_from_openfile_dialog;

const wchar_t* wstr_file_name = (const wchar_t*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(multi_language_str)).ToPointer();

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> converter;

std::string str_file_name = converter.to_bytes(wstr_file_name);

OpenVideo(str_file_name.c_str());

Marshal::FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)(void*)wstr_file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off using this, which has less hassle of managing resources, and is more exception-safe thanks to pin_ptr's destructor:

```
array<unsigned char>^ bytes = System::Text::Encoding::UTF8::GetBytes(str_from_openfile_dialog + L'\0');
cli::pin_ptr<unsigned char> pinned = &bytes[0];
const unsigned char * puString = pinned;

OpenVideo(static_cast<const char *>(puString));
```